# Nothing works to vertical center two divs next to each other

Tags: html, css, centering

First post! Yay!
Hi Stackoverflow I have a problem.

I have a div with 100% width and auto height with two things int it. A text box and an image. I want the two to always be vertical centered to each other but I can't seem to find out how! Here's my code.

Edit: It's about the imacshowcase.

HTML

```
<section id="responsiveshowcase">
    <h1>Services</h1>
    <div id="imacshowcase">
        <div id="imacshowcasedesc"><img  src="img/icons/code.png" alt="">
            <h1>Website Development</h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.</div><img class="wow animated slideInRight" src="img/imacshowcase.png" alt=""> </div>
            <br class="clearBoth" />
    <div id="macbookshowcase"><img class="wow animated slideInLeft" src="img/macbookshowcase.png" alt="">
        <div id="macbookshowcasedesc"><img src="img/icons/seo.png" alt="">
            <h1>SEO</h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.</div>
            <br class="clearBoth" />
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
#responsiveshowcase {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

#imacshowcase {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;

}

#imacshowcasedesc {
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    float: left;
}

#imacshowcase > img {
    width: 30%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 10%;
}

#imacshowcasedesc > img {
    width: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#imacshowcasedesc > h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
    font-size:1.5em
}

#macbookshowcase {
    width: 100%;
}

#macbookshowcasedesc {
    width: 40%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 10%;
}

#macbookshowcase > img {
    width: 30%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 5%;
}

#macbookshowcasedesc > img {
    width: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#macbookshowcasedesc > h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36805954/how-to-align-elements-within-a-well/36811121#36811121 this guy had a similar problem and has 2 different solotions in the answers for you to try out

Comment: you're using the same  id mulitple times on your page I can't express how invalid your HTML is!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it is generally best practice to not do much styling with ID tags and to reserve them mostly for javascript functions. Use css classes for styling instead.

Secondly, **Flexbox is your friend**

```
#responsiveshowcase {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Flexbox does work, but stretches my image's height to 100%! So theres another problem!

Comment: If you have to support IE you may have trouble with Flexbox, http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: What happens when you add a specific height to the image? 

And @plasticpie is correct if you are targeting versions of IE below version 11.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

```
#responsiveshowcase {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}
```

Didn't seem to work but

```
#macbookshowcase {
width: 100%;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}
```

did!